# How to store R objects (lists) in an SQLite database?

Tags: r, sqlite, sqldf, rsqlite

I was just wondering whether it is possible to store R lists directly in a SQLite database (and of course retrieve them) via sqldf or RSQLite.

Comment: @agstudy Yes we can! However I am a bit worried about the performance of this hacky way as soon as the data gt bigger...

Comment: @Jack I mean you can't store a list as it is in a classic data base. Ritchie kindly detail more this in his answer.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate as it is `sqlite`-specific.

Answer (score 4):

See my other, better answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26098290/134830

---

Ragged objects like lists don't fit well with the rectangular nature of database tables.  You have a few options to work around this limitation.

Convert your list to text using `dput`, and store that in a text column.  Then `dget` it when you retrieve it back from the database.

You can also store your data as XML or JSON in a text column, and parse it when you retrieve it.

If you don't care about the contents being readable, you can also store it as a binary blob, using `saveRDS` (and retrieve it using `readRDS`).

All these methods have the downside that you can't do in-database analytics on them.  They are only suitable for using the database as a data storage medium.

If you want to work with your data inside the database, you'll have to [make it rectangular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3699543/134830).

---

More detail on the RDS method.  This is actually more of a pain than I first anticipated, since yes, you need to write to file.

```
l <- list(x = 1:5, y = letters)

saveRDS(l, "tmp")
bits <- readBin("tmp", "raw", 1000)
# Then send the raw data to the DB

# On retrieval reverse the process
writeBin(x, "tmp")
readRDS("tmp")
```

---

A possibly easier alternative to the RDS method.

```
bits <- charToRaw(paste0(deparse(l), collapse = ""))

# And the reverse:
eval(parse(text = rawToChar(bits)))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer - readability is not an issue. I only need the DB as organized storage medium with concurrent access by many subprocesses. However I would need to save a file first before I can store it in the DB would I not? Could you give me a minimal example for the saveRDS approach with RSQLite?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, slightly wrong search before posting, c.f.

[Storing R Objects in a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395115/storing-r-objects-in-a-relational-database)

Lets just elaborate a minimal working example:

```
library(RSQLite)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "test.sqlite")
dbSendQuery(conn = db, "CREATE TABLE test (ID INTEGER, DATA STRING)")
l <- list("super", "important", "stuff")
dbSendQuery(conn = db, sprintf("INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '%s')", 
                               rawToChar(serialize(l, NULL, TRUE))))
unserialize(charToRaw(dbReadTable(db, "test")$DATA))
```

happy coding!