# How to unserialize php-serialized data in R?

Tags: r, rmysql

In mysql database, have data serialized by php as below:

```
"a:564:{s:13:\"caltime\";s:6:\"65.26\";
```

I use Rmysql to query these data, but donot know how to unserialize them in R.
Thank for any help!

Comment: For anyone else that ends up here, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44719384/3473055) answer useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read PHP serialize() data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820191/how-to-read-php-serialize-data-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have any inbuilt function to unserialize data. You can't do it. You need to do from application level

Answer (score 0):

if my data is :

```
$a= array( '1' => 'elem 1', '2'=> 'elem 2', '3'=>' elem 3');
$b=serialize($a);
```

then print_r($a) produce following o/p:

```
a:3:{i:1;s:6:"elem 1";i:2;s:6:"elem 2";i:3;s:7:" elem 3";}
```

and then print_r($b) produce following o/p:

```
Array ( [1] => elem 1 [2] => elem 2 [3] => elem 3 )
```

i hope its help you